# Form - If placeholder is set move Label (js)

Tags: javascript, forms, label, placeholder, translate

i need some help with my form.

I want the same form like this site :

https://secure.mypass.de/sso/web-fullpage/login?service=https%3A%2F%2Flo.la.welt.de%2Fuser%2Fredirect%3FredirectUrl%3Dhttps%253A%252F%252Fwww.welt.de%252F%253Fwtrid%253Dcrossdevice.n24.desktop.directhome&wt_eid=2148165323200346732&wt_t=1483902148371

They say, if a placeholder is set, the label should move.
Can someone help me with this, i dont know how i can do it.

```
Here is my Demo: http://codepen.io/CRYP3/pen/WRvyxw
```

Comment: this is not a placeholder, they use a `label` over the input. You can move the label on focus

Comment: but if the placeholder is set, the label still are on the same position.

Comment: just check in `onfocus`, if the input has value, then move, otherwise do nothing

Comment: have you a idea how i can move the label if the value is set? With addclass?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this code, I didn't check it, so no idea if this will work:

```
$(function() {
    $("#username").focusin(function() {
        if($("#username").val().length < 1)
            $("#label").addClass("active");
    });
    $("#username").focusout(function() {
        if($("#username").val().length < 1)
            $("#label").removeClass("active");
    });
});
```

1st you need to set `id` for your label, then you need a class `active`, that will actually move the label.